# Initialize an execute af:quickQuery default criteria on page load

Tags: java, oracle-adf

My requirement is to pass a parameter to a bounded task flow  to initialize an `af:quickQuery` component on load of a page in ADF.

```
 <af:quickQuery label="Search" searchDesc="Search" id="qryId1" 
                 value="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery1.quickQueryDescriptor}"
                 model="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery1.queryModel}"
                 queryListener="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery1.processQuery}">
    <f:facet name="end">
      <af:commandLink text="Advanced" rendered="false" id="cl1"/>
    </f:facet>
 </af:quickQuery>
```

and based on that parameter value I want `<af:quickQuery>` to fetch the result from Database and display it on the page when the page first loads up.
I know about `InitialQueryOverriden` property but it doesnot match with my case since I need to set the passed parameter to quickQuery and perhaps I need to overwrite the queryListener and set the parameter value to the implicitly created criterion.

Can anyone provide me a suitable solution to this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a bounded taskflow then you can write a method and make this method default activity. This way it will run first.
Please see this post, it may be helpful http://www.jobinesh.com/2011/03/using-component-for-filtering-child.html